# Extract information from outlook with python

Tags: python, outlook

Good morning

How can I extract a specific information from outlook with python code.

Thanks in advance.
Merie.

Comment: We really need more information to help you. For example if you are using Outlook with an Exchange Server, there is a Python package that can help you out (https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is an extremely broad question, I  would recommend looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

This should have some of the basic stuff to get you started.